# What is the returning size of Google Cloud results? Why it does not work like in eclipse?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Ok, I have this code & it works fine in eclipse

```
public static long getPropertyMaxIDStronglyConsistent(String entityName, String propertyName, Key parentKey){
            // Order alphabetically by property name:
            //Key parentKey=KeyFactory.createKey(parentEntityName, parentName);
            Query q = new Query(entityName, parentKey).setAncestor(parentKey)
                            .addSort(propertyName, SortDirection.DESCENDING);

            //List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
            List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q)
                            .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));        
            if(results.size()>0){
                Entity e=results.get(0);
                long maxID=(Long)e.getProperty(propertyName);


                return maxID;

            }
            else{
                return 0;
            }

    }
```

However, after deployed to Google App Engine, it messed up everything.

Based on my research, it seems that Google return extra row when we get `List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(5));` unlike MYSQL and JDBC Driver

For example, if the real table has 2 rows, it will return 3 rows & if we `Entity e=results.get(0);` it somehow does not show anything.

Comment: Over many years in production, and I've never seen it returning the wrong number of entities.

Comment: You use `parentKey` twice when defining your query. It's unnecessary - you basically set the ancestor key twice.

Comment: But it's ok if "**return (results.size())**" so the query is not wrong

Comment: Also, if it's wrong why it works fine in eclipse?

Comment: (1) It's not wrong. It's unnecessary. (2) The name of your method implies that you want strong consistency. Queries are not strongly consistent.

Comment: but when I do this **List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q)                    .asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(1));**, seem limit 10 does not work, but limit 1 works

Comment: It always works. You either see eventual consistency issues, or there is something wrong with the data.

Comment: If I was wrong then Why I would work just fine in eclipse?

Comment: There is no Datastore in Eclipse. You mean that it "works" on a local server, which App Engine SDK emulates to behave like a Datastore. The data on your local server is totally different from your production Datastore, and eventual consistency is only approximated using the settings in your run configuration.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, I found the problem. If the Kind got indexed, then it works fine, but if has not indexed yet, then it does not work. The question is that, why it took like a few hours for Google to Index the Kind.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin, what are  composite indexes & why they do not appear right away & what is "serving" status & is there any way to force it appear right away?.

Comment: You can add a composite index to the index definitions files manually.